# 1 table or 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table called UserComments.

It contains 3 columns:

> id, user_id, and comment_id.

I query this table 2 separate ways.

> 1 by user id and

`1 by comment id`.  Both of these fields are indexed.

I want to add an additional column tags.

I will only need this column when querying by **comment id**.

Does it make more sense to add the column to the existing table (and not return it back to avoid data transfer)?

OR

Create a new table and perform the join when necessary?

Why is 1 better than the other?

Comment: What is the datatype of Tags and maximum or average length of the field?

Comment: What will be in tags? If it's like the tags to your question sql, mysql ..etc I would create a Tags table containing TagID, TagName. Since comments can have multiple tags I would create a new table containing CommentID, TagID

Comment: Generally speaking, more tables is better.  Reason being, you want to avoid redundant data.  Your use should be on it's own.  Your comments table should have it's own ID and a field for the UserID - join on that.  And subsequent things you need that are not comments or new users should have their own tables with the same scheme.

Comment: Sorry, it would be a text probably. Or maybe a large varchar.

Comment: It sounds like there would be multiple tags per comment, in which case you would want a second table so that you could correctly model the one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @durbnpoisn why is avoid redundancy important? It seems like now a days ppl go nosql and do nothing but create redundancy.

Comment: @endyourif redundant data takes up more space and there is no reason for it. Proper database design should have no redundant data.

Comment: Because it's bad design.  And one that you will regret later.  You will limit your expandability right from the start.  Just because people seem to enjoy doing it because it's easier, doesn't mean it's the right way.  And what Humdinger says there goes right along with what I'm saying - he's right.

Comment: nosql != relational database like mysql.  Designs for each are very different.  What @Tsukasa and durb are saying is correct.

Comment: I'll add one table for tags, one table for commentsTags and I'll add a comentTagId in Comments table, not in userComments table

Comment: @Horaciux why wouldn't you add the CommentID to your commentTags table? By adding commentTagID to comments you just limited it to 1 tag.

Comment: @Tsukasa CommentTagID reflects one-to-many tags in comments

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server : Pick one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a separate table for the specific purpose of tags. 
Lets take this stack overflow question as an example. You have created a question with 3 tags. This means that ONE comment has THREE tags or in other words a one-to-many relationship.
The proper way to model one-to-many is with a separate table. Now, lets look at the differences.

One Table:
You will have one table. You will not be able to model a one-to-many so you will have to create your own method for having multiple tags such as a CSV for the tags.

example:

```
id, user_id, comment_id, tags
'2',  '276',    '2738',  'mysql,sql,sql-server'
```

Can you see how this is getting confusing already? You will need to write your own code to parse out the csv. Now, imagine you wanted to search by tag. Oh man... the nightmare that will become.. and the slowness if you use a sql regex or like...

On the other hand, a two table would have a second table

```
comment_id, tag
123, mysql
123, sql
123, sql-server
```

You grab all entries with 123, you have your list. Now if you want to search by tag, EASY.

My guess is you already have a separate table somewhere else for users, and you grab all users comments using this comment table. You did that inherently because users and comments are a one-to-many relationship. Same concept here.

Comment: @TMNT2014 to be honest I just felt like adding that for no apparent reason. I removed it from the answer.

Comment: I would add yet another table. Why have a column with n instances of the word 'sql-server'

Comment: @Tsukasa you are right. You could technically break this out to a many-to-many relationship and have a relations table. However, the benefit of this is relatively pointless if you have a somewhat small table. For beginners, I think a one-to-many is sufficient. Plus, it is not hard to convert it to a many-to-many later if needed

Comment: @Humdinger I would take into consideration of space. varchar(n) containing 'sql-server' compared to a smallint field with the value of 1. so 'sql-server' takes up its bytes once rather than n times.

Comment: @Tsukasa I repeat, the space difference is very small for small data sets. People who are concerned about database space, normally know how to do this stuff anyways. While I agree a many-to-many is more secure, maintainable, and efficient -- a one-to-many is simplistic and sufficient for a beginner. Lets not get too crazy too fast.

Answer (score 1):

Adding as answer because consensus agrees:

Generally speaking, more tables is better. Reason being, you want to avoid redundant data. Your User table should be on it's own. Your comments table should have it's own ID and a field for the UserID - join on that. And subsequent things you need that are not comments or new users should have *their* own tables with the same scheme.

From this you will have the benefit of having your Users sitting on their own, and be able to easily join each user to an indefinite number of comments with no redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. I would create a table just for tags rather then having a column containing n instances of say 'sql-server' tag when you can related it to a Tag table. So sql-server has an id of 1. int 1 over varchar 'sql'server' takes less space plus allows easy expand on.

Comment

```
CommentID
..etc
```

UserComment

```
UserCommentID
CommentID
UserID
```

CommentTag

```
CommentTagID
UserCommentID
TagID
```

Tag

```
TagID
Description
```